Query builder Relation ManyToMany without the association entity
The context is a Symfony 6 project wired with Doctrine 3. I have a ManyToMany relation between Projet and Employe, and in the list page of the projects i want to display only the projects for whom the logged in user (an Employe) is assigned. So the aim is to use tue queryBuilder in the  ProjetRepository to return that list, with a method which take the Employe as argument. I can give a link to the the open source project I'm working in : so with a LAmp Wamp or any stack with Php 8.3 and Apache server, (any database you want) , you can clone the main branch. Beware, the work is in progress, so even with the DataFixtures, you won't be able to log in with the pre-loaded data with the doctrine way to do that. But you will be able to register another user, and to set the role in the db for example.
you can clone this : https://gitlab.com/HenriLabe/task-linker-example.git
(then add a user , put him a ADMIN role in your db in order to edit a project
I try to get all entities (projets) related to given other one (employe), enities are mapped as ManyToMany.
I want to use the query builder in the Repository of the entity i want to get a list
I have a piece of code which do not throw any exception or error, but array returned is empty while data are set as I want in database
public function findProjectsByGrantedEmployee(Employe $employe): array 
{
    $employeId = $employe->getId();
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')->andWhere(':employeId IN (\'p.employes\')')->setParameter('employeId', $employeId)->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}


Let's debug your database query
-dql: "SELECT p FROM App\Entity\Project p WHERE :employeId IN ('p.employes')"

Employer ID (:employeId) is in the p.employes field. However, p.employes is not a primary field in the data. This is a ManyToMany relationship that is used to pass data through an intermediary table. Querying the control ID as text "p.employes" makes no sense.
I propose two solutions.
Using a collection from the entity class
public function __construct(
    private readonly EmployerRepository $employerRepository
) {
}

#[Route('/test', name: 'app_test')]
public function index()
{
    $employer = $this->employerRepository->find(1);
    $result = $employer->getProjects()->toArray(); <--- get collection
    dd($result);
}

Creating a valid query by using QueryBuilder
public function findProjectsByEmployer(Employer $employer): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->innerJoin('p.employer', 'e', Join::WITH, 'e = :employer')
        ->setParameter('employer', $employer)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}

Table project_emplpyer data:

Dump result, for two ways:


I agree with your way of queryBuilding, , but it throws a [Semantical Error] line 0, col 55 near 'e WITH e = :': Error: Class App\Entity\Projet has no association named employe .... And That's quite normal, as Projet entity as only a 'employes' collection property
